# Recursively try all urls alphabetically and download files

Tags: apache, http, curl, wget

Is there a way to recursively and alphabetically test all possible urls inside a folder and recursively download all the files to a local machine?

I am aware of curl and wget, but I'm not sure if they work like this.

Say... http://www.domain.com/something/

from there download recursively all files that are located in subfolders like aaa, aab, aba, baa, abb, bab, bbb, ccc... with all possible amounts of letters / numbers and custom limits for the script user.

Comment: how do you know what all the subfolders actually are ?

Comment: the key thing is not knowing the subfolders' names and thus trying all the possible combinations.

Comment: That sounds like quite aggressive web crawling to maybe even a [denial of service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) not sure I want to help out

Comment: I wondered this too. Apparently it's too aggressive..